# remove a UIView on touchevent

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

I'm adding a `UIView` in  the current `UIViewController`. I need to remove a `UIView` when touched anywhere on the screen. I have a `UIButton` in the `UIView`. But if I click `UIButton`  then also the `UIView` is removed.

Actually I have added a button(Signout) in `UIView` which when click  should dismiss the `currentview` and go to `homeViewController`. But if I tap anywhere on the current view other than the button on `UIView` then `UIView` should be removed. But in my case if I click button then also `UIView` is removed.

```
logout= [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210,lbllogin.frame.origin.y+lbllogin.frame.size.height, 80, 50)];
logout.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
btnSignout = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnSignout addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(aMethod:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
btnSignout = CGRectMake(0,0,80,13);
[logout addSubview: btnSignout];
[self.view addSubview:logout];


        UIButton *btnsignout=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        [lblsignout setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 13)];
        lblsignout.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        lblsignout.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblsignout .font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14];
        lblsignout.text=@"Sign out";

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [logout removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to track the touched location,that means you have to check whether you have tapped in the frame which is of button. if you have tapped in the location of button i.e. frame of button then don't call to removeFromSuperView. else call to removeFromSuperView.

```
//pseudo code,not actual code
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if( touches.x & touches.y is in button frame)
{
[logout removeFromSuperview];
}
else
{
[btnSignOut removeFromSuperview];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding this functionality you have to go to InterfaceBuilder-identity inspector - class and set class UIControl.and then connect ViewController's main view to your .h file by ctr-drag and create action for touch up inside.like :

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTapped:(id)sender;
```

and in .m file

```
 - (IBAction)backgroundTapped:(id)sender {
        //remove your view here
    [logout removeFromSuperview];
    }
```